# Is there any way to have my html page refresh/reload itself after a function in the django view.py tab completes?

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

I want to have my page refresh itself after a successful download of a zip file since successive attempts to click the submit button result in an error, and the only way to remedy it fairly easily is to manually refresh/reload the page.  I was wondering if there is a way to set it up so that once the zip is completed the page will refresh itself without the user having to worry about it.  Doing it this way also kills two birds with one stone, since I want to disable the submit button to prevent users from spamming it, but if I end up having the page refresh I could just out right remove it after it's clicked.

Here is my HTML code:

```
{% load static %}

<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static '/styleSheet.css' %}">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edstore">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">


    <!--BOOTSTRAP ASSETS-->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Quicksand:wght@400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>



</head>
<body>

   <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action=""  method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}

        <div class="main_Body">
            <div class="section">
                <h1>Fileconverter</h1>
                <br>

                <label for="file_field" class="custom-file-upload">
                    <i class="fa fa-cloud-upload"></i>Updload File(s)</label>
                <input type="FILE" id="file_field" name="file_field" class="file-upload_button" multiple>
                <label id="file_name"></label>
                <br>
                <br><br><br>
            
            <br>
            <button type="submit" class="file-submit__button" onclick="formDisableButton()" id="submitButton">Testing</button> <!--onclick="formDisableButton"-->

        </div>
    </form> 
</body>


<footer>
    <p>Click "Choose File(s)" and select the files you want to convert.</p>
    <p>Once you click "Submit" the job will start.</p>
    <p>Upon completion, a zip folder will be downloaded in your browser.</p>
    <p>Do not click the submit buttons multiple times. If the tab is loading, the job is being processed.</p>
</footer>

</html>


<script>

  document.querySelector("#file_field").onchange = function(){
  document.querySelector("#file_name").textContent = this.files[0].name;
  }

  const tempButton = document.getElementById("submitButton");
  function formDisableButton(){
    // tempButton.disabled = true;
    // setTimeout(formEnableButton, 10000);
    location.reload();
}

function formEnableButton(){
    tempButton.disabled = false;
}

    /*setTimeout(()=>{
        btn.disabled = false;
        console.log('Button Activated')
    }, 10000)*/


   /* $(function(){
        $("#submitButton").click(function(){
            $("#submitButton").attr("disabled", "disabled");
            setTimeout(function(){
                $("#submitButton").removeAttr("disabled");
            }, 10000)
        });
    });*/

  </script>
```

And here is the views.py file:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.urls import reverse
from django.views.generic.edit import FormView
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

from .forms import FileFieldForm
from django.http import HttpResponse

from .perform_conversion import FileConverter
import zipfile
import io

     
def FileFieldFormView(request, *args, **kwargs):
 
    form = FileFieldForm(request.POST)
    files = request.FILES.getlist('file_field')

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = FileFieldForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():

        
            zip_buffer = io.BytesIO()   
            with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_buffer, "w", False) as zip_file:
            
                for f in files:
                    fileconverter = FileConverter(f.name)
                    fileconverter.run(f.file)
                
                    for img_name, img in fileconverter.output.items():
                
                        data = io.BytesIO(img)
                
                        zip_file.writestr(img_name, data.getvalue())
            
            # Set the return value of the HttpResponse
            response = HttpResponse(zip_buffer.getvalue(), content_type='application/octet-stream')
            # Set the HTTP header for sending to browser
            response['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename=%s" % 'zip.zip'
            response.set_signed_cookie('csrftoken', request.COOKIES['csrftoken'])
        
        
            # Return the response value
            return response

            
        else:
            return HttpResponse('Form Invalid')

    else:
        return render(request, 'pages/file_converter.html')
```

Based on what I've seen after doing digging before asking this question, Ajax seems to be the right direction for things, but I have no experience with it and everything I find online doesn't seem to apply to the type of question I'm asking. Also the onclick for the submit button doesn't work, but that's not a main problem right now. TBH any help would be massively appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to refresh the active django webpage without using return redirect(...)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72968167/is-there-a-way-to-refresh-the-active-django-webpage-without-using-return-redirec)

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript `onclick` to change the button class from `class="file-submit__button"` to something like `class="file-submit__button-disabled"`, and of course add the corresponding css.